# What would be the equivalent to LIKE '%[^a-z]ACCESS[^a-z]%' in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-like

I'm trying to get an output where it has the string `access` in it and has space on either side. Using `ILIKE '% access %'` isn't working as I'm getting result with `'accessibility` in it.

Tried `ILIKE '% access %'`.

Comment: I don't see how `% access %` returns `accessibility`.  Did you mean `%access%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You could try using \b which means word boundary, along with 'i' parameter for case insensitive. This gracefully handles the beginning/end of text.

You can tinker with ACCESS vs access and adding/removing the 'i' parameter.

```
WITH CTE(COL) AS ( SELECT 'any ACCESS any' union all select 'Access blah blah'union all select ' blah blah Access' union all select 'Access'
            union all   SELECT 'any apple any' union all select 'apple blah blah'union all select ' blah blah apple' union all select 'apple' union all select 'accessibility')
SELECT
  COL
, REGEXP_LIKE(COL,'^.* ACCESS .*$' )        MARCOTHESANE
, REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(COL),'.* ACCESS .*')     BITCOUB
, REGEXP_LIKE(COL,'.*(\\bACCESS\\b).*','i')    ALT_ANSWER
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH
s(s) AS (
 SELECT 'any ACCESS any'
)
SELECT
  s
, REGEXP_LIKE(s,'^.* ACCESS .*$') AS is_rx_like
FROM s
-- out        s        | is_rx_like
-- out ----------------+------------
-- out  any ACCESS any | true
```